# Documentation for the stub

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

In see it in peers `RSpec` codes alot and I need to write `RSpec` too but I don't know what it is and how to use it,etc so I Googled it but all that comes up are just more specific questions people have asked about using it in different situations, but first I need to learn it I guess. Where is the documentation for it ? Is it part of RSpec?
The frameworks we use at work are `FactoryGirl` and `Rpsec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find all basics here http://everydayrails.com/2012/03/12/testing-series-intro.html !